# Python 3 range iteration uncertain

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.4.0 on an ubuntu 14.04 system.

This is a bubble sort procedure, but no, this is NOT homework.  I'm having problems with a range.  This is just stemming from an interest in learning python.

The program statement is:

```
for i in range(siz):
```

siz has been set to 20, but it's iterating from 0 to 18.  Here's the output.

```
======================================\n

Traditional Bubble Sort\n

20 54 7 array('I', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
---> \n

siz = 20\n

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
=========================================
```

and here's the code segment that produced this.

```
print(siz, rows, colw, a)
s = input('---> ')

print("siz =", siz)

for i in range(siz):
    print(i)
```

========================================

I thought range was supposed to iterate from 
zero to siz-1, given the constraints of the statement.

What am I missing?

Cordially,

Dave

Comment: Thi prints 0 to 19 as expcted: for i in range(20):
    print(i). Is there something missing in your code snippet?

Comment: Same as jaco. This prints 0 to 19 with python 3.4

Comment: Can you print something afterwards? I'm wondering if the program is returning before printing the last line.

Comment: No, nothing missing in the code snippet.  Program was execution was fine.  I'm at a loss to explain how this happened, but now when I go into Python, and do a straight range(20), I do get 0-19.